# Python not printing entire string as URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I have a URL like `https://...com?var-Table_Type=*&var-DC=abc`

When I print the URL, the entire URL is printed but only half of it is highlighted in blue as a URL, so when I click the output it doesn't take me to the actual link.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to elaborate and give some reproducible code example. Under which circumstances are you executing your code? (System, IDE etc.)

Comment: Since `*` is not a valid RFC 3986 URI symbol, your terminal (or wherever this display goes) interprets only strictly valid part of it as an actual URL. This has nothing to do with python, `echo`'ing your URL would give the same result. Search for percent encoding (most likely `urllib.parse.quote` in python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://example.com?var-Table_Type=*&var-DC=abc'
encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=':/?&=*')

print(encoded_url)
```

In the encoded URL, each special character has been replaced with its corresponding URL-encoded representation. For example, : is encoded as %3A, / is encoded as %2F, ? is encoded as %3F, & is encoded as %26, and * is encoded as %2A.

Comment: I still have the same issue, after * it doesn't consider it as a URL

Comment: That's the issue of terminal not code. You can try a different terminal for it.